# Ненадежная проверка - пост с такими значениями полей может уже быть в БД до момента запроса на создание

Tags: python, django, юнит-тесты

Делаю тест формы отправки поста. Ревьювер сделал неоднократное замечание "Ненадежная проверка - пост с такими значениями полей может уже быть в БД до момента запроса на создание. Стоит взять последний пост, отсортировав предварительно по id." Не совсем понимаю как реализовать эту проверку.

Вот эта строчка:

```
def post_create_form(self):
...
self.assertTrue(Post.objects.latest('id'))
```

В этой же проверке есть еще замечание рвеьювера "Выборка поста из БД повторяется выше - можно выполнить ее один раз и пост положить в переменную" и указывает на вот эту строчку:

```
def post_edit_forms(self):
...
Post.objects.get(self.post.id).author, self.post.author
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше реализовать? Я был уверен что я правильно сделал.

Весь код:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test import Client, TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from ..forms import PostForm
from ..models import Group, Post

User = get_user_model()


class PostCreateFormTests(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.author = User.objects.create_user(username='NoName')
        cls.post = Post.objects.create(
            text='Тестовый текст',
            author=cls.author,
        )
        cls.group = Group.objects.create(
            title='test_title',
            description='test_description',
            slug='test-slug'
        )
def setUp(self):
    self.authorized_author = Client()
    self.authorized_author.force_login(self.author)

def post_create_form(self):
    """Валидная форма создает запись в БД."""
    posts_count = Post.objects.count()
    form_data = {
        'text': 'Текстовый текст_2',
        'group': self.group.slug
    }
    response = self.authorized_author.post(
        reverse('posts:post_create'),
        data=form_data,
        follow=True
    )
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse(
        'posts:profile', kwargs={'username': self.post.author}))
    self.assertEqual(Post.objects.count(), posts_count + 1)
    self.assertTrue(Post.objects.latest('id'))

def post_edit_forms(self):
    """Валидная форма редактирует запись в БД>."""
    posts_count = Post.objects.count()
    form_data = {
        'text': 'Измененный текст',
    }
    response = self.authorized_author.post(
        reverse('posts:post_edit', kwargs={'post_id': self.post.id}),
        data=form_data,
        follow=True
    )
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse(
        'posts:post_detail', kwargs={'post_id': self.post.id}))
    self.assertEqual(Post.objects.count(), posts_count)
    self.assertEqual(
        Post.objects.get(self.post.id).text, form_data['text']
    )
    self.assertEqual(
        Post.objects.get(self.post.id).author, self.post.author
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен.

1. В методе проверки создания формы положил последний пост в переменную post_latest = Post.objects.latest('id'),тем самым сделав сортировку по id, ну потом только сделал тест на валидность формы.

   **def post_create_form(self):**

   ```
    ...
    post_latest = Post.objects.latest('id') 
    self.assertEqual(Post.objects.count(), posts_count + 1) 
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse(
        'posts:profile', kwargs={'username': self.post.author})) 
    self.assertEqual(post_latest.text, form_data['text']) 
    self.assertEqual(post_latest.group.id, form_data['group'])
   ```
2. Я выборку из БД положил в переменную edit_post_var = Post.objects.get(id=self.post.id)

   **def post_edit_forms(self):**

   ```
    ...
    edit_post_var = Post.objects.get(id=self.post.id)
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse(
        'posts:post_detail', kwargs={'post_id': self.post.id})) 
    self.assertEqual(Post.objects.count(), posts_count) 
    self.assertEqual(edit_post_var.text, form_data['text']) 
    self.assertEqual(edit_post_var.author, self.post.author)
   ```

Оказалось проще чем казалось. Оставлю здесь вдруг еще кому-нибудь понадобится.